# Splitting a Bounded Context - administration and execution

Tags: domain-driven-design

TLDR: not quite sure whether I got my Bounded Context right.

**Situation**

I have a domain model in one Bounded Context:

[image: Domain Core]

Entire model is in the same bounded context. Bounded context has two responsibilities:

- administering products/rules/parameters
- parsing/executing products' rules

Business invariants pertaining to administering products, rules and parameters are contained within the aggregates themselves. The existing Product/Rule/Parameter model is **very** suitable for this.

**Problem**

Problems arise when executing rules. In order to execute a (set of) rules, I need to fiddle around a lot, query and filter across multiple collections:

- A specific Product
- All of the Rules belonging to that Product
- All of the Parameters belonging to those Rules.
- Sometimes I even need to filter across those collections for very specific combinations and this is getting more and more cumbersome.

So I created a new class `ExecutionProduct` as a placeholder for all the filtered data needed by the `ExecutionRule` + started adding filtering logic to `ExecutionProduct`. It is not a perfect fit for the execution model + there is a lot extraneous data within the aggregates, but I can manage.

**Question**

`ExecutionProduct` got me thinking whether I should move parsing/executing responsibilities into a standalone Bounded Context, since that would allow me to morph existing data into more suitable format for execution. Please note that when executing rules, there is no need to persist anything: it consist of running through all the rules and doing complicated filtering, comparison and other business logic.

Comment: What is your domain? It's a bit unclear from your examples. The level of abstraction you are working with does not seem very useful unless you are actually in the business of creating rules engine software. What I mean is, by separating rules, parameters, and the data they act upon, you are essentially creating a CRUD system inside of a DDD system. So unless your domain it is truly creating such a system, I would suggest trying to make this system more concrete.

Comment: Yes, I am creating a business rule system. The part with the `Product`, `Rule` and `Parameter` is the core of the system.

Comment: @king-side-slide: Which part would you consider CRUD? Administration or execution?

Comment: The purpose of DDD is to combine business rules *with* the data they act on. Doing so in a way that properly modularizes the *behavior* of a system is a far-from-trivial exercise in modeling, but results in a powerful abstraction of it's functional requirements. A procedural (CRUD) approach generally takes the form of: `Command -> Query -> (data) -> Validation -> Mutation -> Persistence`. DDD transforms the above into: `Command -> Query -> (domain) -> Mutation -> Validation -> Persistence`. By asking *telling* your data (domain) to mutate itself, you can be assured...

Comment: ... that two mutations of the same state undergo the same validation. This is not so with CRUD (without discipline), because validation is not hard-coded to mutation in the same way. Essentially, your "objects" are just bags of data being passed around, inspected, and validated according to some command context. Your system represents the same thing. `Products` are passed to `Rules` with `Parameters` for validation. Because a `Product` is unable to validate itself, business rules are a result of configuration.

Comment: There is nothing *wrong* with this if your domain is to make a rules engine. There is no other way to make it work other than through configuration (saving some way of literally changing source code when rules are added). You are being tasked with creating a domain model, whose purpose is to create an entirely different (client created) domain model at run-time.

Comment: @king-side-slide: You make good points here. My product's rule validation logic has completely slipped into the domain service layer. The whole execution context has nothing to do with the administration context. It is one thing to create a new rule and assign values to it and map it to a product. It is a different (more technical) thing to execute the rules and cross-reference different products and what not.

Comment: I think I will go for two Bounded Contexts, one for `Administration` and one for `Execution/Validation`. `Validation` will be dependent on `Administration`'s Product/Rule/Parameter complex as a data source, but will morph it within its Anti-corruption layer into a more suitable format. That will take a lot of clumsiness and complexity out of the `Administration` bounded context.